# select limited data from column

Tags: php, mysql

I need to select limited number of characters from one column. I've tried :

```
SELECT substring_index(COLUMN_NAME, 250);
```

BUT the column name will be identified as normal text string.

EXAMPLE : I have column "Description" and I want to retrieve first 250 characters of the description to put into php variable.

It works when using substring NOT substring_index.

Comment: Edit it again to tell us why `substring(description,1,250)` doesn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With more clarification from the poster, putting the answer here, in case he/she chooses to accept it.

```
substring(description,1,250)
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you just need to add "AS Description" after the substring function call so the column gets renamed back to just Description in your PHP result array?